# Django1.11 - Show media on localhost

Tags: django-media, django-1.11

I'm having hard time to display media on local system.. the problem is that:

`{{ producer.img.url }}`

gives me a url path relative to the page I'm browsing, so it always fails to locate the file. It actually prints something like:

```
media/media/djprofiles/john_0VtCrdA.jpg
```

which obviously fails (note the missing initial "/").

Following Django docs, I added in my **urls.py**:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
]
urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    ...
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

and **settings.py** is as follow:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
```

The `img` field is defined in **models.py** as follow:

```
img = models.ImageField(upload_to=settings.MEDIA_URL + 'djprofiles')
```

I know there are already many questions relative to showing media on local system, but none seems to provide me with a working solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

in **settings.py**?

Comment: yes, that was part of the solution, along with `img = models.ImageField(upload_to='djprofiles', null=True, blank=True)`